# What is the dimension of this manifold?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S_n = \{X \in  \operatorname{Sym}_n(\mathbb{R}): X > 0, \det(X) = 1\}$. Here $ \operatorname{Sym}_n(\mathbb{R})$ means $n \times n$ symmetric matrices over $\mathbb{R}$, and $X > 0$ means $X$ is positive definite. It is claimed that $\dim_{\mathbb{R}}(S_n) = \frac{1}{2}n(n+1)-1$. Why is this true?

$S_n$ is clearly a subspace of the space of $n \times n$ symmetric matrices with determinant 1, which should have dimension $\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)-1$. It seems wrong that $S_n$ has the same dimension.

Comment: Note that $S_{n}$ is an open set in the space of $n\times n$ symmetric matrices with determinant $1$. The dimension should then be evident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{Sym}{Sym} \newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}$Everything's fine, because $S_n$ is an *open* subset of the manifold
$$M := \{X \in \Sym_n(\mathbb{R}) \mid \det(X) = 1\}
$$ and hence will be a submanifold of $M$ with the same dimension.

For each $1 \leq k \leq n$, let $\mu_k : M_n(\bR) \to \bR$ be the function defined by
$$
 \forall A \in M_n(\bR), \quad \mu_k(A) := \det \begin{pmatrix} A_{11} & \cdots & A_{1k} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ A_{k1} & \cdots & A_{kk} \end{pmatrix};
$$
since $\mu_k$ is a polynomial in the matrix coefficients, it is continuous on $M_n(\bR)$, and hence, *a fortiori*, on the submanifold $M$ of $M_n(\bR)$. But now, by [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion), a matrix $X \in \Sym_n(\bR)$ is positive-definite if and only if $\mu_k(X) > 0$ for every $1 \leq k \leq n$, so that
$$
 S_n = M \cap \mu_1^{-1}((0,+\infty)) \cap \cdots \cap \mu_n^{-1}((0,+\infty))
$$
is manifestly open in $M$.